# Nginx, exclude access log with regex

Tags: nginx

In the access log of my nginx web server I have logs like this:

```
XX.XX.147.5 - - [20/Oct/2022:18:42:59 +0000] "GET /my-subfolder/readiness HTTP/1.1" 200 1496 "-" "EF-Strati-HealthCheck-Client/1.0" "11.16.133.0"
XX.XX.94.5 - - [20/Oct/2022:18:42:59 +0000] "POST /my-subfolder/some-path-to-exclude/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OFsjAj9&sid=2Mufsq23xBh8FRLWAFtD HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "https://www.myapp-example.com/my-subfolder/home" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX"
```

How can I make a rule to exclude logs a access that has `/socket.io/` in?

Is there a way to put some regex? Like:

```
location ~ /(.*)socket.io(.*)/ {
  access_log off;
}
```

I tried that but I keep getting logs:

```
XX.XX.29.4 - - [20/Oct/2022:21:03:13 +0000] "GET /my-subfolder/some-path-to-exclude/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OFtDAhA.0&sid=pxCY9pYkRXFp4ULZAAAS HTTP/1.1" 200 1 "https://www.myapp-example.com/my-subfolder/home" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX"
```

Comment: didn't test it, but you could use [conditional logging](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/monitoring/logging/#enabling-conditional-logging) together with [mapping](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) of the [variable $request_filename](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_filename)

(see the first link for how it all plays together)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line just before your `access_log` directive line.

```
set $writelog 1;
if ( $uri ~ ^/socket.io/ ) {
    set $writelog 0;
}
```

And then do the logging only when `$writelog` is set, like this:

```
access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log main if $writelog;
```